# Regex for substitution in latex

Tags: latex, substitution

I have a tex file that contains text and latex commands of the form

```
This is an acronym \acsu{RNS} and another acronym \acf{FHE}.
```

The commands are the `\acsu{RNS}` and `\acf{FHE}`. I would like to extract the text within the brackets and the output should be

```
This is an acronym RNS and another acronym FHE.
```

All of the commands start with \ac*, followed with one or two more characters like \acsu, \acs, \acf etc.

I tried the following sed command

```
sed -i.bkup 's/ [\][a-z]*{\([^]]*\)}/ \1/g' part.txt
```

but this replaces the first occurence of \acsu{ and the last } in the last occurence, thus the output is

```
This is an acronym RNS} and another acronym \acf{FHE.
```

Note there are numerous commands in the tex file that involve {} brackets but I would like to replace only those starting with \ac. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that

`sed -i.bkup 's/\\ac[a-z]*{\([^][}]*\)}/\1/g' file.txt`

does the trick.